# Mono support for Entity Framework on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework, mono

I have an existing application using MVC5 and EF6, and am looking at using Xamarin Studio on OSX rather than using VS on Parallels.

The compatibility chart (http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) says that older versions of EF should be available, but are there any gotchas that I need to be aware of?

If I'm currently using LocalDB, can I easily migrate to SQL Lite?

Cheers,
Bartek

Comment: Changed from Xamarin to Mono, as you are not targeting any Xamarin platforms (Xamarin.Mac, Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android).

Comment: EntityFramework is a Microsoft driven technology, so up-to-now there are only limited reports on success, such as http://fxjr.blogspot.hk/2014/02/using-entity-framework-6-with-npgsql-210.html. Thus, when choosing to target SQLite, make sure you do enough research on the possibility, and be prepared for potential issues.

Comment: So, how it goes? I'm trying to do the same as you did (almost a year ago). I wonder if you achieve this or came back to parallels

Comment: Came back to Parallels, although will revisit with ASP.NET 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pure mono, you can use Xmamarin.Mac, it's mono but with support for Mac (XIB files, cocoa bindings, etc). It comes in two flavors, opensource and paid.

Said that, I'm personally using EF with Xamarin.Android/iOS with SQLite and still had no problems, so I assume using it with Xamarin.Mac will work (and for extension Mono 3.4.x should also work, Xamarin.Mac uses the LINQ part from mono).

And changing from one database to another, if you have the correct provider for LINQ and it's purely managed should not be a problem (avoiding the database differences, of course).

For reference, here you have a thread from Xamarin about using Linq with SQLite:  http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7256/share-experience-for-linq-with-sqlite

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Mac and after I added EntityFramework package I still can't see `System.Data.Entity` namespace:/ Can't use DbSet class